# How to solve the wave equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, differential-equations

The solution of classical wave equation
$$\nabla^2\textbf{A}=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\textbf{A}}{\partial t^2}$$
is
$$\textbf{A}(r,t)=\textbf{A}_0(e^{i(\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}-wt)}+e^{-i(\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}-wt)})$$

So how to solve this 2nd order PDE in detail?

Comment: Thats just one possible solution that represents a plane wave when $\mathbf A_0$ is purely real. There are infinitely many others that have quite different behavior.

Comment: Read up on Fourrier transformation, it comes in very handy in theses kind of equations.

Comment: Trial functions is usually one method.

Comment: Look in a textbook?

Comment: Google D'Alemberts formula.

Comment: Do you just want a general solution or is there more to the question? To solve this in an arbitrary 3D medium can be somewhat involved.

Comment: I want a general solution, but also the particular one for a plane wave.

Answer (score 4):

The standard method is to use separation of variables. Let's solve the scalar wave equation instead as it is much more instructive (and the vector wave is just three independent scalar waves):

$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2\phi=0.$$

Separation of variables comes into play when we suppose that, for a particular solution, the dependence on each variable can be separated by a product. Here I'll do it as follows. Suppose we can write

$$\phi(t,\mathbf r)=T(t)R(\mathbf r).$$

Substituting into the wave equation we get

$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{d^2T}{dt^2}R-T\nabla^2R=0.$$

Dividing by $TR$

$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{1}{T}\frac{d^2T}{dt^2}-\frac{1}{R}\nabla^2R=0. $$

It is easy to see that the first term is a function of $t$ only, while the second is a function of position only. Since they are completely independent variables, we can say that both terms are constant and add up to zero.

$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{1}{T}\frac{d^2T}{dt^2}=-k^2,\quad\frac{1}{R}\nabla^2R=-k^2,$$

Where we've written the constant as $-k^2$ for real $k$ since we want things to oscillate.  The time part is the simple harmonic oscillator. It has solutions

$$T(t)=c_+e^{ikct}+c_-e^{-ikct}.$$

The second equation is the Helmholtz equation, and its solutions have different convenient expressions on each different coordinate system. If we suppose cartesian coordinates and apply separation of variables once again, we get three harmonic oscillator equations, with the solution

$$R(\mathbf r)=R_0e^{-i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r}$$

For any $\mathbf k$ such that $\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf k=k^2.$
Now we have a particular solution for the wave equation when we multiply $T$ and $R$:

$$T(t)R(\mathbf r)=(c_+e^{i||\mathbf k||ct}+c_-e^{-i||\mathbf k||ct})e^{-i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r}$$

For any $\mathbf k\in\mathbb R^3$. The coefficients are arbitrary complex numbers.

This is however just a particular solution. To get the full picture we need to write the superposition for all possible $\mathbf k$. This is usually written

$$\phi(t,\mathbf r)=\int_{\mathbb R^3}^{}\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} \left(f_+(\mathbf k)e^{i||\mathbf k||ct}+f_-(\mathbf k)e^{-i||\mathbf k||ct}\right)e^{-i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r}$$

For any two complex valued functionals $f_\pm: \mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb C.$

In the vector wave case these two final functions would map to vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ as well. If we impose our wave as some kind of physical manifestation, it's better for it to be real, i.e. $\phi=\phi^*$. We can write

$$\phi^*(t,\mathbf r)=\int_{\mathbb R^3}\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\left(f_+^*(\mathbf k)e^{-i||\mathbf k||ct}+f_-^*(\mathbf k)e^{i||\mathbf k||ct}\right)e^{i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r}$$

Which we can compare with the first expression for $\phi$ and get that
$$f_-(\mathbf k)=f_+^*(-\mathbf k)$$

And therefore we can write a physical wave solution to the problem fixing a single function $f=f_+:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb C$ as

$$\phi(t,\mathbf r)=\int_{\mathbb R^3}\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\left(f(\mathbf k)e^{i||\mathbf k||ct}+f^*(-\mathbf k)e^{-i||\mathbf k||ct}\right)e^{-i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r}. $$